# Use Flat Catalog Category disable

Tags: flat

Use Flat Catalog Category in Catalog is disable or Hide, Why?
[image]

Comment: probably a module you installed, which disables this forcefully

Answer (score 2):

The flat category config field has a frontend model `adminhtml/system_config_form_field_select_flatcatalog`. Look for it in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml`.

The frontend model is actually a block that renders the field.
This block is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Select_Flatcatalog`. If you take a look at it, you will see this method:

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    if (!Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isBuilt()) {
        $element->setDisabled(true)
            ->setValue(0);
    }
    return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
}
```

$this means that the element is disabled if `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category_Flat::isBuilt()` return `false`.
Digging deeper you end up in the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::isBuilt()` that returns false if there is no flat table for any store view or if the flat tables don't have entities.

Reindexing should fix everything.

Comment: How to bypass disabled products from reindexing magento 2 [EE]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably disabled because **catalog_category_flat_store_x** table is empty.
Go to **System > Index Management** and reindex **Category Products** option and see if that enables the option.

Answer (score 0):

This option will always be disabled if **no** products are in the store (so by default, it will be disabled until you add a product & reindex)